# How to generate string using a JSGF grammar in Java?

Tags: java, grammar, context-free-language

[JSpeech Grammar Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-jsgf-20000605/) allows user to specify tags for separate strings in curly brackets as follows:

```
 <jump> = jump { primitive jump }  [up] |
     jump [to the] (left { primitive jump_left } |right { primitive jump_right } );
```

or

```
 <effects> = nothing happens { NOTHING_HAPPENS } | ( [will] die | dies ) { OBJECT_DESTRUCTION } | (get|gets) new (coin|coins) { COIN_INCREASE };
```

Using tags is described more thoroughly in section 4.6.1 of the referenced [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-jsgf-20000605/).

In **Sphinx4** you can catch these tags using `getTags()` method in **RuleParse**. So if user says "*jump to the left*" the following tag will be returned "*primitive jump_left*"

Now, I would like to do exactly the opposite - given the tag, I would like to match it to the string. So for "*NOTHING_HAPPENS*" I would like to get "*nothing happens*" or for "*OBJECT_DESTRUCTION*" an arry with all possible options: "*will die, die, dies*".

Is there any such method that can parse grammar files in such way or do I have to hardcode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sollution to this is to generate all possible sentences defined by JSGF file. This can be done easily with dumpRandomSentences or getRandomSentence methods provided by Grammar classin Sphinx and give them back to the Recognizer which will print out the tags.

Sample code from my project:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        String utterance = grammar.getRandomSentence();
        String tags;
        try {
            tags = parser.getTagString(utterance);
            System.out.println(tags+" ==> "+utterance);

        } catch (GrammarException e) {
            error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```